# Problem with localhost when installing utorrent.

Tags: utorrent

I installed everything correctly but  I cannot connect to the localhost in the web browser. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux systems, uTorrent runs as a webserver. The server must be started and you will need a web browser to connect to it. I’ll recommend other torrent clients for Ubuntu.

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. Paste the following code and hit Enter.

```
wget http://download.utorrent.com/linux/utorrent-server-3.0-25053.tar.gz
```

Next, run the commands below to extract uTorrent files to the /opt directory.

```
sudo tar xvzf utorrent-server-3.0-25053.tar.gz -C /opt/
```

Then run the below commands to change the permission on uTorrent-server folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
```

Next, run the commands below to link uTorrent server to the /user/bin directory.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/utserver /usr/bin/utserver
```

Finally, run the commands below to start uTorrent.

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-v3_0/
```

If you get an error about libssl or any other error.so package missing, run the commands below to install it, then try starting it again.

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386
```

Open your web browser (Firefox) and type :

```
localhost:8080/gui/
```

The username is admin and leave the password field empty.

Hope it will solve your problem ...

Answer (score 0):

If You have installed everything correctly and utorrent is not running
.Then try

```
utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/ &
```

It is most general problem when we try to run utorrent after a system restart.

Then go to `https:<your_ip_adress>:8080/gui`

ipadress could be retrieved by `ifconfig`

If `ifConfig` is not installed then run `sudo apt install net-tools`